# Showing this error when i run following SQL code? I trying to solve this code by sub-query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

```
Select c.CustomerName, pl.ProductName as 'Product Name', o.OrderDate as 'Order date', 
Count([Address]) as 'No of Places', SUM(pl.Price * od.OrderQty) as 'Total Amount'
From Customer c
Inner Join [Order] o ON o.CustomerId = c.CustomerID
Inner Join OrderDetails od ON od.OrderId = o.OrderID
Inner Join ProductList pl ON pl.ProductID = od.ProductId
where c.CustomerID = (select cc.CustomerID from Customer cc where 
cc.CustomerName = 'Mr.A')
```

But showing this error

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Column 'Customer.CustomerName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: each time you use aggregate functions like (Sum , Count ...etc) you have to use Group By for the rest of columns you select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgot to specify the group by clause, try this :

```
Select c.CustomerName, pl.ProductName as 'Product Name', o.OrderDate as 'Order date', 
Count([Address]) as 'No of Places', SUM(pl.Price * od.OrderQty) as 'Total Amount'
From Customer c
Inner Join [Order] o ON o.CustomerId = c.CustomerID
Inner Join OrderDetails od ON od.OrderId = o.OrderID
Inner Join ProductList pl ON pl.ProductID = od.ProductId
Inner join Customer cc on c.CustomerID=cc.CustomerID and cc.CustomerName = 'Mr.A'
group by c.CustomerName, pl.ProductName, o.OrderDate
```

Comment: but i want to solve this problem using SubQuery which you didn't use in this code.

Comment: its the same, subquery or not... Use your query, but add group by with columns like my query